# Select rows with minimum number of occurrence of value by group

Tags: r, dplyr

In this dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(
  File = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C"),
  value = c(1.111, 1.222, 0.001, 0.999, 0.12, 1.23, 0.000, 0.55, 0.666, 0.666))
```

I want to select those rows where at least **two `value`s are `> 1`** per group. I know how to select those rows where at least *one `value`* is `> 1` per group:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(File) %>%
  filter(any(value > 1))
```

How do I have to adapt this to filter as specified above?

**Expected**:

```
  File  value
  <chr> <dbl>
1 A     1.11 
2 A     1.22 
3 A     0.001
4 A     0.999
```

Comment: Ah yeah, that simple! Thanks please post as answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`filter(sum(value > 1) > 1)`. `sum(value >1)` counts how many values are greater than 1, and the second `> 1` keeps groups that have 2 or more values greater than 1.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(File) %>%
  filter(sum(value > 1) > 1)
```

Comment: Need ungroup at end to prevent subsequent calculations being inadvertently done by group.

Comment: I won't make assumptions about whether OP's next step is going to be grouped or not.

Comment: Or using `base R` `subset(df, ave(value > 1, File, FUN = sum) > 1)`